# How can one call a ItemView function manually?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have the following `ItemView` which is wrapped inside a `CollectionView`:

```
define(deps, function($, _, Backbone, CountriesTemplate, Globals) {
  return Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    className: 'unstyled countries',
    itemView: Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

      tagName: 'li',
      template: CountriesTemplate,

      events: {
        'change': 'toggleState'
      },

      triggers: {
        'click': 'toggleState'
      },

      toggleState: function() {
        var index = Globals.defaultCountries.indexOf(this.model.id);
        index === -1 ? Globals.defaultCountries.push(this.model.id) : Globals.defaultCountries.splice(index, 1);
        this.model.set('checked', !this.model.get('checked'));
      }
    })
  });
});
```

The collection is bound to a list of checkboxes and it is manually bound to svg circle elements which represent countries. Checking/unchecking the checkboxes is not problem and invokes the `toggleState` as it should. The problem arises when trying to manually trigger the event when a svg circle element is clicked.

The code that tries to trigger a click event manually:

```
// country is a "model"
checkbox.prop('checked', true);
// Changes the checked attribute but does not call toggleState.        
country.set('checked', true); 
// Nothing happens here.
country.trigger('click');
```

So, what is the correct method for invoking `toggleState` manually?

## Update:

Using [damienc88](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205914/how-can-one-call-a-itemview-function-manually/20205974?noredirect=1#20205974)'s answer I made the following changes inside `itemView` to make the trigger work.

```
itemView: Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  template: CountriesTemplate,

  events: {
    'change': 'toggleState'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'toggleState', this.toggleState);
  },

  toggleState: function() {
    // Code.
  }
})
```

Calling `model.trigger('toggleState')` from outside now works as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to invoke `toggleState` on the ItemView directly, you can just call `itemView.toggleState();`  This only works if you have access to that specific itemView object.  You might not know it.

Alternatively, you can trigger an event on the model, and the ItemView can listen for that event on its' model:

`this.listenTo(this.model,'toggleState',this.toggleState)`. Your CollectionView then needs to call `model.trigger('toggleState')`.